# Getting 404 when trying to revoke access token from Google OAuth2 revoke endpoint

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I am using angularx-social-login for authenticating users with Google.

The token is retrieved like this:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=issueToken&response_type=token%20id_token&login_hint=LOGIN_HINT&client_id=CLIENT_ID&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200&scope=openid%20profile%20email&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200
```

The response is a JSON object, and the access token is `responseData.access_token`.

For revocation, I first download https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration, find the revocation endpoint as https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token=TOKEN and following https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#tokenrevoke (select the tab HTTP/REST in the example box) I send the request with:

```
curl -D- -H "Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token=TOKEN"
```

But instead of a successful response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Thu, 16 Jan 2020 18:07:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: ESF
Content-Length: 1710
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443";    ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000
```

And the body of the response contains something like "The requested URL ... was not found on this server.  That's all we know."

I have already tried with `DELETE` or `POST` or passing the token in the `Authorize` header as a Bearer token instead of a query parameter but at no avail; the response is always the same.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

POST command works for revoke. please try with below curl command:

curl -d -X -POST 'https://oauth2.googleapis.com/revoke?token=PUT_TOKEN_HERE' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: please try once with the curl command I have shared. I have posted it only after testing. or share the exact curl POST command you have used. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For reasons known only to Google they don't appear to publish the correct revoke endpoint.

The one I've been using for the last year is listed in their python client library [tests/data/client_secrets.json](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/17c8516ba497849945fdabf37ae746b43229d53b/tests/data/client_secrets.json): "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke"